# Oracle 12c: using user defined functions results and In Clause

Tags: oracle, function

I have a function(funct_A) that returns a varchar in quotes
Select funct_A from dual returns 'A1234';

I want to use the result from funct_A in an IN clause

This returns 100 --> select count(E.tickets) from event E where E.ticket_number in ('A1234').

This returns 0 --> select count(E.tickets) from event E where E.ticket_number in (funct_A).

How is this accomplished?

How is this accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

You probably wouldn't.  If your function always returns a single value, you'd just use an equality condition rather than an `IN`.  Assuming your actual goal, though, is for the function to return multiple values, you likely want a pipelined table function instead

```
create or replace type ticket_tbl is table of varchar2(10);

create or replace function funcA
  return ticket_tbl
  pipelined
is
begin
  pipe row ('A1234');
  pipe row ('B5678' );
end;
/

select *
  from event e  
 where e.ticket_number in (select column_value
                             from table( funcA ) );
```

Comment: Thx for response; the function returns many quoted varchars - its dynamic; this is why a simple equality can not be used. Just to confirm...the values returned from the statement below:

select funct_A from dual

can not be executed in an In clause? It does return quoted varchars

Comment: @javaCoder - Well "can not" is a bit of an overstatement.  More like "should not".  You certainly could write code that would parse the list of values that were returned, remove the quotes, and use that in an `in` list.  Or you could use dynamic SQL to generate the statement with the `in` list.  The dynamic SQL approach tends to have both performance and security concerns, particularly if this is a commonly used query in your system.

Comment: @javaCoder - Parsing the string into rows is probably possible but it's not great architecture to have your function concatenate values into a string just to have the caller reverse that work to get back to rows.  The pipelined table function would be a vastly cleaner architecture.